# In Swift, what is a 'progression'?

Tags: swift, iteration, control-flow

According to the [Control Flow](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120) section in the *Swift Language Guide*,

> The `for-in` loop performs a set of statements for each item in a range, sequence, collection, or progression.

I'm pretty sure I know what three of these are:

1. **range**: something defined with the [range operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID73), `...` or `..<`
2. **sequence**: something that conforms to the `SequenceType` protocol (documentation not anywhere obvious, but various people have [reverse-engineered](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/swift-sequences) it)
3. **collection**: either of the Swift [collection types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html), i.e. `Array` and `Dictionary`

(I note #3 is probably redundant as `Array` and `Dictionary` both seem to conform to `SequenceType`.)

But what's a "progression"? Is it some fourth thing, or was the writer just being wordy?

---

**ETA:** I see there's a `CollectionType` protocol as well, so that explains #3.

Comment: Weird. I suspect the latter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first mention I see of "progression" besides the for-in documentation is in the comments of the swift framework where the stride methods are defined.

```
func stride<T : Strideable>(from start: T, to end: T, by stride: T.Stride) -> StrideTo<T>
```

> Return the sequence of values (`start`, `start + stride`, `start + stride + stride`, ... *last*) where *last* is the last value in the progression that is less than `end`.

```
func stride<T : Strideable>(from start: T, through end: T, by stride: T.Stride) -> StrideThrough<T>
```

> Return the sequence of values (`start`, `start + stride`, `start + stride + stride`, ... *last*) where *last* is the last value in the progression less than or equal to `end`. Note:: There is no guarantee that `end` is an element of the sequence.

So in short, **"progression" refers to the `Strideable` protocol similar to how "collection" refers to the `CollectionType` protocol** and the classes and structs that conform to it.

Numeric types (Int, Double, Float, UnsafePointer, Bit, etc...) tend to conform to this protocol so they may be incremented/decremented for `for in` loops. Full inheritance graph for the `Strideable` protocol found [here](http://swiftdoc.org/protocol/Strideable/hierarchy/).

Answer (score 4):

What you are probably looking for is this kind of loop ( for in stride )

```
for i in stride(from: 1, to: 10, by: 2) {
    println(i)
}
```

that is the new syntax replacement for

```
for var i = 1; i < 10; i += 2 {
    println(i)
}
```

Comment: as pythons `for i in range(1,10,2)` but I like the verb `stride` better.

Comment: I think the new syntax looks much better and readable than the old one

Answer (score 3):

Answer of this question lies in Mathematics.

There are two types of progression in mathematics.

[Arithmetic Progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) and [Geometric Progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)

From Wiki: [Arithmetic Progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)

> In mathematics, an arithmetic progression (AP) or arithmetic sequence
>   is a sequence of numbers such that the difference between the
>   consecutive terms is constant. For instance, the sequence 5, 7, 9, 11,
>   13, 15 … is an arithmetic progression with common difference of 2.

[Geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)

> In mathematics, a geometric progression, also known as a geometric
>   sequence, is a sequence of numbers where each term after the first is
>   found by multiplying the previous one by a fixed, non-zero number
>   called the common ratio. For example, the sequence 2, 6, 18, 54, ...
>   is a geometric progression with common ratio 3. Similarly 10, 5, 2.5,
>   1.25, ... is a geometric sequence with common ratio 1/2.

Comment: So Apple feels free to use words in their documentation that a well-educated software developer should know. Even if they have three or more syllables :-)

Comment: That is one definition of "progression", but not what Apple means in this case.

Comment: @OrangeDog I Think Apple Guys have kept this definition in their mind for "progression".

Comment: While you provided a definition of progression, you did not explain what a progression is within the context of the Swift language, which is what the question asked. I would imagine that is why somebody gave you a downvote.

Comment: ya context should be relate to Swift language